# How to Display php myadmin Record count

Tags: php

I have a php website with phpmyadmin database hosted on cpanel. I have a link called "vacancy.php" linked to database table called "vacancies". Vacancies holds all the list of available jobs to be display on "vacancy.php".

"vacancy.php" display 20records perpage. I already have page navigation links but I want to add record count to display e.g "1 - 20 of 71records" before the page navigation links.

I used

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vacancy";
   $ctpg=$result->num_rows;
?>

<div class="body-text4 pull-right">
  <strong>1</strong> - <strong><?php echo "$count"; ?></strong> of <strong><?php echo "$count"; ?></strong> records
</div>
```

it returned just the records number. Please assist

I need it to desplay as 1-20 of 71records for first page 21-40 of 71records for second page etc

Comment: what you are asking for is ```pagination```

Comment: You have a query to get count(*) but you're not executing it. $result is still pointing to your last executed query/resultset.